# Probit analysis shows no significant variables

Tags: stata, probit

In my probit output all p values are insignificant. I want at least some of my variables to be significant.  How I correct it?

My variables are: crossbreed, age2, gender, education experience2, fullparttime, localbreed, farmsystem, ownland2, hirelabor, expensemoyr2, milkincome2, vetanaryattendence2, vetanaryservice, traninggot, furthertraning, health.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Ummm.... you should at least consider the possibility that there genuinely is no significant evidence that your explanatory variables are related to the response.  However, also have a read of some of the answers on this site about model selection.  I'm afraid that beyond that it will be very difficult for anyone to answer your question in a helpful way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Now I can understand there is a relationship between y and x variables.

Answer (score 6):

There are various reasons you could get insignificant results.

@Peter Ellis raised one reason (often overlooked): Your model is wrong. That is, there really isn't a good relationship for your model to find.

Second, you could have poor power. What is your sample size?

Third, you could have poorly measured variables. You list the variable names, but that just lets us guess at what they are and how they are measured. Badly measured variables make it harder to find relationships.

Fourth, there could be nonlinear relationships.

Fifth, there could be interactions.

Sixth, there could be collinearity.

Seventh, there could be overfitting.

(There are probably a few more, but that's off the top of my head).

Comment: Thanks you,I thought that model selection is correct,but the thing is selected variables have some problem.I removed some variables and I found that there are some outliers in the variables,after remove that variable I could get significant p values.